# Why does using my print method with std::cout result in an error?

Tags: c++, family-tree

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fam
{
    public:
        char you, urmom, urdad;
        void addPerson(char y, char m, char f)
        {
            you = y;
            urmom = m;
            urdad = f;
        }
};

class Tree: public Fam
{
    public:
        void showFamtree()
        {
            cout<< "Name: " << you << endl;
            cout<< "Mother's name: " << urmom <<endl;
            cout<< "Father's name: " << urdad <<endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    Tree tree;

    char a,b,c;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    tree.addPerson(a,b,c);

    cout<< "Family tree: " << tree.showFamtree() <<endl;

    return 0;    
}
```

I wanted to print the family tree with
the person's name, mother's name, father's name
but when I compile it, I get the following error:

> invalid operands to binary expression (`basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >` and `void`)

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages, this is certainly not C.

Comment: Also, quotes are for quotes. not for normal text.

Comment: I edited your post to give it a title that carries some information and I included some error message for your problem. (The latter was generated with clang, you may change that to the error message your compiler yields if you want to.) For the future, please make sure your titles describe the problem and your posts include relevant error messages. Have fun on this site.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. All apologies if my question didn't make that much sense to you. I'm just a Computer Science student trying to save my grades this semester so I can finally shift to my desired major.

Answer (score 2):

`tree.showFamtree()` returns nothing (i.e. `void`), it doesn't make any sense to try to pass it to `std::cout`. You might change

```
cout<< "Family tree: " << tree.showFamtree() <<endl;
```

to

```
cout << "Family tree: " << endl;
tree.showFamtree();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define `operator <<` like this

```
ostream& operator << ( ostream & ostr , const Tree & t ){
    ostr << "Name:" << t.you << endl
        << "Mother's name:" << t.urmom << endl
        << "Father's name:" << t.urdad << endl;
    return ostr;
}
```

then you can use

```
cout<< "Family tree: " << tree <<endl;
```

This is known as [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) in C++.

Comment: Why `static` function?

Comment: Why the `static`? € Too slow.

Comment: There is no meaning much. I remove it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You're welcome. For a complete answer, you should explain what's wrong with the current approach IMO. (Already upvoted though as I guess you explained what OP is trying to do.)

Comment: it was omitted because it was already described @songyuanyao is the cause when I try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use something similar to this:

```
void showFamtree()
{
    cout<< "Name: " << you << endl;
    cout<< "Mother's name: " << urmom <<endl;
    cout<< "Father's name: " << urdad <<endl;
}
```

with:

```
cout << "Family tree: " << tree.showFamtree() << endl;
```

One C++ approach would be to use std::stringstream, as in:

```
std::string showFamtree()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Name: " << you << endl;
    ss << "Mother's name: " << urmom <<endl;
    ss << "Father's name: " << urdad <<endl;
    return (ss.str());
}
```

---

I also often add a label.  So consider using

```
std::string showFamtree(std::string label)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << label;
    ss << "Name: " << you << endl;
    ss << "Mother's name: " << urmom <<endl;
    ss << "Father's name: " << urdad <<endl;
    return (ss.str());
}
```

and change invocation to

```
cout << tree.showFamtree("Family tree: ") << endl;
```

---

Note - Perhaps the label should be on its own line, for consistent white space on the left of the 'tree'.